# How do I get this canvas animation script to work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas

I wrote this canvas animation script in hopes to use it on my portfolio website, but it is basically non-functional in Firefox, and I am not sure why. The script draws stars on the canvas that slowly rotate, and if you hold down the mouse button they spin faster creating trails. It works awesome in chrome, but is extremely slow and choppy in Firefox.

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let mouse = {
  x: window.innerWidth / 2,
  y: window.innerHeight / 2
}

let stars = [];
const starCount = 800;

class Star {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = () => {
      c.save(); 
      c.beginPath(); 
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2); 
      c.fillStyle = this.color;
      c.shadowColor = this.color;
      c.shadowBlur = 15;
      c.fill(); 
      c.closePath(); 
      c.restore(); 
    };

    this.update = () => {
      this.draw();
    };
  }
}

let colors = [
  "#A751CC",
  "#DE9AF9",
  "#F9E0F9",
  "#B5ECFB",
  "#5F86F7"
];


(initializeStars = () =>{
  for(let i = 0; i < starCount; i++){
    let randomColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    let randomRadius = Math.random() * 2;
    let x = (Math.random() * (canvas.width + 400)) - (canvas.width + 400) / 2; 
    let y = (Math.random() * (canvas.width + 400)) - (canvas.width + 400) / 2;
    stars.push(new Star(x, y, randomRadius, colors[randomColorIndex]));
  }
})();

let opacity = 1;
let speed = 0.0005;
let time = 0;

let spinSpeed = desiredSpeed => {
  speed += (desiredSpeed - speed) * 0.01;
  time += speed;
  return time;
}

let starOpacity = (desiredOpacity, ease) => {
  opacity += (desiredOpacity - opacity) * ease;
  return c.fillStyle = `rgba(18, 18, 18, ${opacity})`;
}

let animate = () => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.save();

  if(mouseDown){
    starOpacity(0.01, 0.03);
    spinSpeed(0.012);
  }else{
    starOpacity(1, 0.01);
    spinSpeed(0.001);
  }

  c.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  c.rotate(time);

  for(let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++){
    stars[i].update();
  }

  c.restore();

}


window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX - canvas.width / 2;
  mouse.y = e.clientY - canvas.height / 2;
});


window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  stars = [];
  initializeStars();
});


let mouseDown = false;

window.addEventListener("mousedown", () =>{
  mouseDown = true;
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  mouseDown = false;
});

animate();
```

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/SheWolf/pen/EdwKVv) to the demo on Code Pen; any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use rect instead of arc to draw your stars:

   c.rect(this.x, this.y, 2*this.radius, 2*this.radius);
2. remove the blur It's extremely expensive:

   //c.shadowBlur = 15;

You can use a radial gradient going from opaque in the center to transparent in his stead.

Comment: Thanks! It was the shadowBlur Firefox was having an issue with.